# Javascript Acting on Bullet List

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bulletted list like this:

```
<ol>
 <li>Point 1</li>
 <li>Point 2</li>
 <li>Point 3 has sub-points
  <ul>
   <li>Sub-point about something</li>
   <li>Sub-point about something else</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ol>
```

I am transliterating from one writing script to another writing script, so I have to run something against the text in each tag. Here is what my jQuery looks like:

```
$("li").each(function() {
 text = dev2latin($(this).text());
}
```

It makes it look like this:

- Point 1
- Point 2
- Point 3 has sub-points Sub-point about something
  Sub-point about something else

I have tried several iterations of jQuery selectors including `ol>li`, etc, but none of them give the desired result. Thoughts?

Comment: It just adds bullets to the left?

Comment: I don't know if it's me, but I don't understand anything of this. What is the jQuery for ? What is the desired result ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? You want to add bullet points or what? What is it currently doing, nothing? Or something but incorrectly? What is dev2latin, is this a custom function or what?

Comment: The function dev2latin is doing something I didn't think necessary to describe in detail (I mentioned that it's transliteration). If I have अच्छा written in Hindi script it makes it say "accha". Yay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is calling .text() in the parent li will return the text content of the child li also

```
$("li").contents().each(function () {
    if (this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.trim()) {
        this.nodeValue = dev2latin(this.nodeValue)
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lc5ejaL3/)

Comment: Bingo. Thanks for not complaining that you didn't understand what dev2latin() did before answering. Your answer was short and sweet and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch text nodes using [`.contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/), then you can [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) them and perform desired operation.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li")
        .contents()
        .filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType == 3;
        }) //Filter text nodes
        .each(function() {
            this.nodeValue = dev2latin(this.nodeValue); //You can also textContent
        });
});
```

*Here is an example:*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
    }).each(function() {
        this.textContent = this.textContent + 'Updated';
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li>Point 1</li>
  <li>Point 2</li>
  <li>Point 3 has sub-points
    <ul>
      <li>Sub-point about something</li>
      <li>Sub-point about something else</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

$('ol > li').each(function(){ console.log($(this)[0].childNodes[0]); });

$('ul > li').each(function(){ console.log($(this)[0].childNodes[0]); });

Try this way.